# Filtering html from an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a **jquery** `on('click')` on which I am adding html content in an *array*.

```
var starred_messages = [];

$(document).on('click', '.star', function () {
    var starred_msg = $(this).parent().html();              
    starred_messages.push("<div class='clearfix'>"+starred_msg+"</div>");

    console.log(starred_messages);

    $(this).toggleClass('star starred');
});
```

So every time I click on **star** class, html content is added on **starred_messages** *array* and I am using that *array* to show it on a **popup modal**.

So my *array* looks like this when I click two **star** classes.

```
(2) ["<div class='clearfix'><span class="chat-img pull-l…phicon-time"></span>27 Dec, 1:09 pm</small></div>", "<div class='clearfix'><span class="chat-img pull-l…phicon-time"></span>26 Dec, 6:18 pm</small></div>"]
```

I also want to remove the html from the array when I click again.

I tried using **filter** method but it's not working.

```
$(document).on('click', '.starred', function () {
    var starred_msg = $(this).parent().html();
    starred_messages = starred_messages.filter(e => e !== starred_msg);
    console.log(starred_messages);

    $(this).toggleClass('starred star');
});
```

`Note` that I am using `.toggleClass` to change between **star** and **starred**.

Comment: try to add `starred_msg` only to the array so that `filter` will work. You can add `<div>` while you are going to show into the pop-up-model

Comment: @AlivetoDie No, that is not a problem, I tried that. It still doesn't work. The `starred_msg` consists more `divs` inside.

Comment: Why don't you just reset `starred_messages = []` inside your `click` handler?

Comment: console.log(starred_messages); Have you checked its content?

Comment: @fubar Then all the messages will go away. I just want to remove one message not all.

Comment: @Lalit Yes, The content is the array I have included in the question. I can add more items to the array but can't remove them.

Comment: `I also want to remove the html from the array when I click again.` - this isn't clear. If you don't want to remove all existing messages, what conditions determine which message(s) to remove?

Comment: @fubar This condition `$(this).parent().html()`

Comment: @DragonBorn This will get easier if you can share a working snippet using `<>` demonstrating your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that when you toggle from `.star` to `.starred`, you are changing the HTML, and your `filter` only works with exact matches. To solve this, you can store a map of the starred messages, using the existing `id` attribute from your message `li`:

```
const starred_messages = {};    

$(document).on('click', '.star', function () {

    var starred_msg = $(this).parent().html();              
    starred_messages[$('li', this.parentElement).attr('id')] = "<div class='clearfix'>"+starred_msg+"</div>";

    console.log(starred_messages);

    $(this).toggleClass('star starred');
});

$(document).on('click', '.starred', function () {
    delete started_messages[$('li', this.parentElement).attr('id')];
    console.log(starred_messages);

    $(this).toggleClass('starred star');
});
```

When you want to iterate the messages, just use the `Object.keys` method:

```
Object.keys(starred_messages).forEach((id) => { console.log(starred_messages[id]); });
```

EDIT: if for some reason you can't use ES6, this also works in ES5, just replace `let` and `const` with `var`, and use `function(id) { }` insteand of `(id) => { }`

Comment: With this the last message i clicked is being added twice and also I am unable to toggle back from **starred** to **star**

Comment: Are you re-creating the elements that contain the messages?

Comment: Yes I need to show the messages on a modal popup and the classes **star** and **starred** are just bootstrap glyphicons. They don't contain any html. I need their parent elements html, them messages,date info, etc

Comment: How are you tracking the messages? Do they have any identifiers?

Comment: Yes they have but I am not using them. One message is inside an `li` tag. That li contains a user icon, the name, the actual message and the date and they all are inside separate divs. So I am giving a unique id to the every `li`. And the star is also inside the `li` tag.

Comment: Does it work if you extract the id from the li: `$(':parent li', this).attr('id')` instead of `$(this).attr('data-id')` - I'm assuming you mean each `li` has an `id` attribute.

Comment: Selector would be `$('li', this.parentElement).attr('id')`, oops

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162320/discussion-between-dragonborn-and-greg-rozmarynowycz).

Answer (score 2):

I suggest a **more cleaner approach** that you don't create the array at every click, **just create it on the fly when needed**

```
function getStarredMessages()
{
   return $( ".starred" ).toArray().map( function( ele ){
      return "<div class='clearfix'>" + ele.parentNode.innerHTML + "</div>";
   });
}
```

or just `map`

```
function getStarredMessages()
{
   return $( ".starred" ).map( function( ele ){
      return "<div class='clearfix'>" + ele.parentNode.innerHTML + "</div>";
   });
}
```

Your other events should get simpler as

```
$(document).on('click', '.star, .starred', function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('star starred');
});
```

Comment: Much cleaner than mine, tho may run into issues if there's pagination or many hundreds of messages.

Comment: I am getting `ele.innerHTML` is not a function.

Comment: @DragonBorn My bad, it is not a function, check the updates.

Comment: Nope still gives me the same error. Maybe because the classes **star** and **starred** are just bootstrap glyphicons and they don't contain any html inside. I need their parent elements info. The messages, date etc.

Comment: @DragonBorn I changed `ele.innerHTML` to `ele.parentNode.innerHTML` , please check now. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var starred_messages = [];
$(document).on('click', '.star', function () {
   var starred_msg = $(this).html();              
    starred_messages.push("<div class='clearfix'>"+starred_msg+"</div>");

    console.log(starred_messages);
    
  $(this).toggleClass('star starred');
});

$(document).on('click', '.starred', function () {
    var starred_msg = $(this).html();
    starred_msg = "<div class='clearfix'>"+starred_msg+"</div>";
    starred_messages = starred_messages.filter(e => e !== starred_msg);
    console.log(starred_messages);
   $(this).toggleClass('starred star');
});
```

```css
.starred{
  color : blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="star"><div>Star</div></div>
```

Replace

```
var starred_msg = $(this).parent().html();
```

to

```
var starred_msg = $(this).parent().html();
starred_msg = "<div class='clearfix'>"+starred_msg+"</div>";
```

Final Code :-

```
$(document).on('click', '.starred', function () {
    var starred_msg = $(this).parent().html();
    starred_msg = "<div class='clearfix'>"+starred_msg+"</div>";
    starred_messages = starred_messages.filter(e => e !== starred_msg);
    console.log(starred_messages);

    $(this).toggleClass('starred star');
});
```

Because while pushing message into array you are adding extra div into message :-

```
"<div class='clearfix'>"+msg+"</div>";
```

And while removing you are comparing without extra div.

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't work. Earlier I was pushing it without the extra div but was unable to remove it.

Comment: @DragonBorn I have checked it with small working snippet. And working in my case.

Comment: My array is not exactly the same as in the question. It's a lot more huge and is simplified in the question. So is it possible to use .filter?

Comment: @DragonBorn Yes it is possible to use filter.

Comment: @DragonBorn I have added one snippet.

Comment: Your solution is correct but in my case i am using `$(this).parent().html` so my `star` class is inside the parent which is getting changed to `starred` and that's why it couldn't filter it.